# Lat Long won't show on Heatmap with ipyleaflet

Tags: python-3.x, heatmap

I'm displaying congestion on a map with ipyleaflet.

For some reason I can't get a heatmap layer to show over the coordinate I have chosen. Unsure what it is I am doing wrong.

```
from ipyleaflet import Map, Heatmap
from random import uniform
m = Map(center=(-37.814, 144.96332), zoom=11)

heatmap = Heatmap(
    locations=[[(-37.735018, 144.894947)]],
    radius=20
)

m.add_layer(heatmap);

m
```

This is the code.

To be clear - I'm trying to have the heat show at a certain detector which is at the location above (37.735018, 144.894947).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `locations` attribute of a `Heatmap` layer is a list of lists. Each sublist contains [latitude, longitude, intensity].

Please take a look at the documentation and try the example from this page: https://ipyleaflet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_reference/heatmap.html.

Your code should look like this for example:

```
from ipyleaflet import Map, Heatmap
from random import uniform
m = Map(center=(-37.814, 144.96332), zoom=11)

heatmap = Heatmap(
    locations=[
        (-37.735018, 144.894947, 4), # lat, lng, intensity
        (-38, 145, 5),               # lat, lng, intensity
    ],
    radius=20
)

m.add_layer(heatmap);

m
```